# Is it possible to grab a strict range of rows

Tags: javascript

On sharepoint 2010 if I have a list that has 2000 entries and I want to grab only row 400 to 600 is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible you can create a new view or modify the existing view.

- create a new view called TestView
- Filter the View. Select the ID column as filter(see below picture.)

[image]

Comment: This needs to be done through javascript and be a dynamic range each time.

Comment: You should use CSOM CAML query (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx) with @Waqas-Sarwar-MCSE 's filter

Comment: row and ID are two different things!

Comment: @Christophe You're absolutely right. This filter can be applied only if you're certain that no list items were deleted in that list.

Comment: @SlavenSemper even if no item was deleted, it also depends on the sorting rules

Comment: @Christophe Please explain.

Comment: @SlavenSemper if your default view is sorted by title or author for example, rows 400 to 600 will probably not be the items with IDs 400 to 600.

Comment: @Christophe I assumed that user3643344 wants to fetch rows 400 to 600 in order in which they entered the system, not by title or any other column.

Comment: No @Christophe is correct. If there were 200 records input at 400 and then deleted, I would fetching nothing as the next record afterwards would have the ID have 601, not 401.

Comment: Please take a look at my second comment.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the SP 2010 REST API:

```
http://site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName?$skip=400&$top=200
```

[disclaimer: not tested]